# Need to send boolean value in html

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

```
<input type="hidden" name="isActive" data-bind="value : booleanValue" />
```

In the above code, booleanvalue contains boolean value (i.e)true or false.But while saving it converts as string because of value bind in input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how knockout works, however you can create an extender which does the string -> boolean conversation for you. There is already an example for numeric conversion [in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) what you can easily modify:

```
ko.extenders.boolean = function(target, precision) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),               
                valueToWrite = typeof newValue == 'string' ? 
                               newValue.toLowerCase() == "true" : 
                               newValue;
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });    

    result(target());
    return result;
};
```

And you can use it with:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    booleanValue: ko.observable(true).extend({boolean: true})
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4EB6/).